# Macro to define single argument macros

Tags: macros, latex

I am trying to define a macro that will simplify defining later macros.

The behavior I wish to simulate is as follows:

```
\def\mydef#1{MAGIC}

\mydef{foo}
\mydef{bar}

\foo{sometext}% outputs a decorated "foo:sometext"
\bar{sometext}% outputs a similarly decorated "bar:sometext"
```

I have been experimenting with the following:

```
\def\mydef#1{%
  \expandafter\def%      % define when argument is ready
  \csname #1\endcsname%  % set the new macro's handle
  ???%                   % handle arguments to new macro
  {\decorate{#1}{???}}%  % decorate appropriately
}
```

How can this behavior be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your instance, there's technically no need to handle the arguments inside `\mydef`. For example, you can do the following:

> foo:sometext
>   bar:sometext

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mydef#1{%
  \expandafter\def%      % define when argument is ready
  \csname #1\endcsname%  % set the new macro's handle
  {\decorate{#1}}%       % decorate appropriately
}
\newcommand{\decorate}[2]{#1:#2}
\begin{document}

\mydef{foo}
\mydef{bar}

\foo{sometext}% outputs a decorated "foo:sometext"

\bar{sometext}% outputs a similarly decorated "bar:sometext"
\end{document}
```

`\decorate` does take two arguments, even though you only pass it one inside the `\mydef` creation. However, since (La)TeX is a macro-expansion language, the expansion merely inserts `\decorate{.}` into the input stream, leaving `\decorate` to pick up whatever (two tokens) follows after it.

You'll see that `\show\foo` prints the following to the `.log`:

```
> \foo=macro:
->\decorate {foo}.
```

implying `\foo` is void of taking arguments.

If you do wish to capture the argument as part of the macro creation inside `\mydef`, then you should [double the `#`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42463/5764):

```
\def\mydef#1{%
  \expandafter\def%      % define when argument is ready
  \csname #1\endcsname%  % set the new macro's handle
  ##1%                   % handle arguments to new macro
  {\decorate{#1}{##1}}%  % decorate appropriately
}
```

`\show\foo` now shows

```
> \foo=macro:
#1->\decorate {foo}{#1}.
```

meaning `\foo` takes a single (mandatory) argument.